# Can't SSH from 22.04 LTS

Tags: ssh

I'm running 22.04 LTS off an external ssd drive connected to my pc via USB.

I am completely unable to SSH from there to anything, and I have no idea why or what is (not) happening.

I can easily connect from Windows, as well as from my Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS that runs on a regular Lenovo machine.

I followed the instructions at https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-enable-connect-to-ssh-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/ and to sum them up, they are:

```
$ sudo apt install openssh-server -y (Install and enable OpenSSH Server)
$ sudo systemctl enable --now ssh

$ sudo systemctl status ssh:

> ● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
>      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: e>
>      Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-06-28 23:36:54 CEST; 11h ago
>        Docs: man:sshd(8)
>              man:sshd_config(5)    Main PID: 1004 (sshd)
>       Tasks: 1 (limit: 18726)
>      Memory: 3.1M
>         CPU: 29ms
>      CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
>              └─1004 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"
> 
> jun 28 23:36:54 Hakuna systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell
> server... jun 28 23:36:54 Hakuna sshd[1004]: Server listening on
> 0.0.0.0 port 22. jun 28 23:36:54 Hakuna sshd[1004]: Server listening on :: port 22. jun 28 23:36:54 Hakuna systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD
> Secure Shell server.

$ sudo ufw allow 22/tcp (allow port 22)

> sudo ufw status Status: active
> 
> Til                        Handling    Fra
> ---                        --------    --- 
> 22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                   
> 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

From here on, I should be able to ssh to my Pihole:

```
> ssh pi@10.0.0.5 ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.5 port 22: Connection timed out
```

### Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

### EDIT:

From Ubuntu Desktop to target

```
 $ ip addr show
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether f8:75:a4:12:a0:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    3: wlp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 28:7f:cf:2b:9e:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 10.0.0.215/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp5s0
           valid_lft 46015sec preferred_lft 46015sec
    5: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 52:54:00:c5:ce:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    6: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
        link/none 
        inet 10.8.1.4/24 scope global tun0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    11: wlx00c0cab15fb4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DORMANT group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:c0:ca:b1:5f:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

    $ netstat -r -n
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
    0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp5s0
    10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp5s0
    10.8.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
    169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 virbr0
    192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0

$ ping 10.0.0.5
PING 10.0.0.5 (10.0.0.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.0.0.5 ping statistics ---
188 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 191470ms
```

---

From Ubuntu Server 22.04 to target:

```
$ ping 10.0.0.5
PING 10.0.0.5 (10.0.0.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=33.9 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.66 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.94 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.74 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=13.8 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=1.45 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=1.68 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=4.43 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=1.53 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=4.20 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=5.94 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=2.71 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.5 ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 12 received, 0% packet loss,
```

---

From Pihole, which connects to the routher via ethernet:

```
ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:33:8c:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.5/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ netstat -r -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0

$ ping 10.0.0.10 (Pinging my 22.04 server)
PING 10.0.0.10 (10.0.0.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.63 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.77 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.72 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=5.97 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.870 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=6.84 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.10 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 13ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.870/3.134/6.844/2.346 ms
```

---

I have connected from my server to my pihole. It went as planned.

Comment: So the windows desktop and ubuntu server can SSH to the Pihole? But the ubuntu desktop cannot?
Is that right? Are you sure it is on the same network? What do get from this command? ```
ip address show
```

Comment: While I don't know the answer to your question, I'd like to mention that installing a **ssh server** - which you show in your question - is unnecessary to connect via ssh **from** your machine. A server is only needed if you want to connect via ssh **to** your machine from elsewhere. To connect **from** your machine to other machines, a ssh client is sufficient, which is installed in Ubuntu by default.

Comment: And as for your question, please show us the network settings (IP address, netmask & default gateway), ie. output of commands `ip addr show` and `netstat -r -n` both on your Ubuntu desktop and on the Pi.

Comment: Please describe also how you try to connect (which command you use, and how you made sure that the network connection works as expected. And what is the response from `ping 10.0.0.5`?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, so far. I have added the suggested commands from Ubuntu Desktop and will log into the pihole in a moment and to the same from there.

It should be noted, that I haven't been able to ssh to any local address from Ubuntu Desktop, at all. Raspberry Pi's as well as my Ubuntu Server 22.04. I have tried to turn my VPN off, just in case, but no luck either.

Comment: @raj Thanks for you help, I know that installing the ssh server probably wasn't needed, but I have litterally tried anything I could come across and the linuxcapable.com article seemed like it was worth a try anyway. I have added the commands you asked for to the original post. Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like you may have a VPN client installed on your problem computer (IP 10.0.0.215). Try turning the VPN off.

Comment: @user68186 I have tried with and without VPN. No changes. My Windows machine runs the same VPN and there are no issues with that.

Comment: @sudodus You probably missed it, but it's in the top of the post:
> ssh pi@10.0.0.5 ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.5 port 22: Connection timed out
Thanks for your help

Comment: Just because there is no problem with the VPN client in Windows, does not mean the same thing for Linux. VPN service providers sometimes do not have feature parity between clients on these two OSes. Some VPN clients for Linux have command line options to the VPN for the LAN's subnet.

Comment: So ping works, but not ssh. I would also suspect problems because of the VPN. Please try again without it.

Comment: @sudodus It looks like (from the last few lines of the first block of formatted output) ping does not work from 10.0.0.215 to 10.0.0.5. This tells me there is no route to the remote computer. Ergo VPN problem.

Answer (score 3):

Disabling the NordVPN did the trick. Can't believe it was that simple!

To make Ubuntu work alongside NordVPN, I made these changes to my settings:

```
> $ nordvpn whitelist add subnet 10.0.0.0/24
```

I also added my pihole DNS server, while I was at it:

```
> $ nordvpn set dns 10.0.0.5
```

Source:
https://support.nordvpn.com/da/Forbindelse/Linux/1807056062/Installation-af-NordVPN-pao-Debian-Ubuntu-Raspberry-Pi-Elementary-OS-og-Linux-Mint.htm

Now, allow me a moment while I scream into a pillow, before I figure out how to credit @user68186 with providing the correct answers.

And again, thank you all for helping me out. It means a lot.

Comment: Now check your VPN provider's support page and see if they have a setting for the VPN to ignore the LAN subnet. I know NordVPN's command-line client has such a setting.

Comment: I do use NordVPN and I just found the setting. Thanks again, you're awesome, whoever you are!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. After the wait-period don't forget to accept your answer as the correct one by clicking on the gray check mark ✔ next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others. You may also add the NordVPN setting command in your answer, in case someone else has the exact same problem as you.

Comment: @user68186 Done! I can't accept my own answer in another two days. But I'd rather give the credit to you, since you did the hard lifting here. How do I do that?

Comment: Just pay it forward. Learn more about this site from [the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help). Visit this site often and answer some questions if you know the solution.